# JavaScript, писать в консоле внутри блока

Tags: javascript

Насколько я понял, все, что пишется в консоле браузера, выполняется как то, что написано в глобальном скопе. Как можно перейти в какой-то блок, например, в блок функции внутри require? Пример:

```js
require([...], function loaded() {
    ..
    здесь
  
  }
);
```

Comment: вообще непонятно что хотите спросить и какой результат получить

Comment: То, что вы пишете в глобальном скоупе -- выполняется в глобальном скоупе. Влезть в уже существующий локальный скоуп у вас не получится, разве что через пошаговое выполнение кода с точками останова.

Comment: @Grundy ну то есть у меня есть переменная какая-то внутри loaded локальная, и я могу к ней обращаться через консоль в браузере

Comment: @Юрий, нет не можете. Но, вы можете поставить точку остановки внутри этого блока, и когда она сработает, то можно будет

Comment: @Grundy это как раз то, что хотелось узнать

Comment: "Бывало, он еще в постел**е**: ему записочки несут ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставить внутри блока точку останова. Сделать это можно двумя способами. Вписать оператор debugger в ту часть кода, в пределах скоуп которого вы хотите дебажить.

```
function() {
  debugger;
}
```

Или найти нужную строку кода в инспекторе браузера и поставить там брейкпоинт. Так же это можно сделать через WebStorm.

Затем запустить код на выполнение, когда он дойдет до вашего брейкпоинта, вы сможете выполняет код в консоли в пределах скоупа.